# EmberJS - add actions programmatically

Tags: ember.js

I am creating a file menu like this using Ember:

```
{{file-menu menuItems=model.fileMenu.menuItems}}
```

file-menu.hbs:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  {{#each menuItems as |item|}}
    {{component item.type item=item}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Then in my router I am constructing the menu like so:

```
var fileMenu = FileMenu.create();
var orderButton = MenuButton.create({name:"Place Order"});

var fileMenuItem = MenuItem.create({name:"File"});
fileMenuItem.addSubItem(MenuItem.create({name:"Save"}));
fileMenuItem.addSubItem(MenuItem.create({name:"Load"}));
fileMenu.addMenuItem(fileMenuItem);
fileMenu.addMenuItem(MenuItem.create({name:"Edit"}));
fileMenu.addMenuItem(MenuItem.create({name:"Help"}));
fileMenu.addMenuItem(MenuButton.create(orderButton);
```

Now I want to programmatically add an action to my orderButton for when it is clicked. However, I am not sure how to do this. I could only find info on doing it from the template. Is it possible to add actions programmatically and is it acceptable to do that?

Comment: Why don't you want to add the action in the template? If you really want to add it programatically, then do a `addEventListener` in the `didInsertElement` hook of the component.

Comment: Can you setup demo replicating your issue? You didn't include what is `menuItems` and `MenuItem` class, you didn't also give us source code of `addMenuItem` methods and `FileMenu` class.